# How to pass Dynamic Array by reference C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, dynamic, dynamic-arrays

I'm having trouble understanding how to pass a dynamic array by reference in C++.

I've recreated the problem in this small isolated code sample:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void defineArray(int*);

int main()
{
    int * myArray;
    defineArray(myArray);

    /** CAUSES SEG FAULT*/
    //cout<<(*(myArray)); //desired output is 0
    return 0;
}

void defineArray(int*myArray)
{
    int sizeOfArray;
    cout<<"How big do you want your array:";
    cin>>sizeOfArray;

    /** Dynamically allocate array with user-specified size*/
    myArray=new int [sizeOfArray];

    /** Define Values for our array*/
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        (*(myArray+i))=i;
        cout<<(*(myArray+i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't use `myArray[i] = i` Code looks much cleaner that way

Comment: Dynamic arrays are not allowed in C++.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: Calling `defineArray(myArray);` doesn't modify `myArray`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myArray` is passed by value itself, any modification on `myArray` (such as `myArray=new int [sizeOfArray];`) has nothing to do with the original variable, `myArray` in `main()` is still dangled.

To make it passed by reference, change

```
void defineArray(int*myArray)
```

to

```
void defineArray(int*& myArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution is hopelessly complicated. You don't need `new[]`, pointers or even a reference parameter. In C++, the concept of "dynamic arrays" is best represented by `std::vector`, which you can just just use as a return value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> defineArray();

int main()
{
    auto myArray = defineArray();
    if (!myArray.empty())
    {
        std::cout << myArray[0] << "\n";;
    }
}

std::vector<int> defineArray()
{
    int sizeOfArray;
    std::cout << "How big do you want your array:";
    std::cin >> sizeOfArray;

    std::vector<int> myArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        myArray.push_back(i);
        std::cout<< myArray[i] << "\n";
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

`push_back` will work intelligently enough and not allocate new memory all the time. If this still concerns you, then you can call [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) before adding the elements.